# Excel Apply border formatting to adjacent cell based on a cells value

Tags: excel

Let's say I have data like this:

```
Bill No.    Total
    001     100.00
    002     200.00
    003     300.00
    004     400.00
    005     500.00
  Total    1500.00
```

How can I use conditional formatting or any other method in excel, to add borders to the cell that's to the right of `Total` in `Column A`?

So it looks like:

```
Bill No.    Total
    001     100.00
    002     200.00
    003     300.00
    004     400.00
    005     500.00
           -------- 
  Total    1500.00
           ========
```

I've tried `Home> Conditional Formatting> Format Only Cell that Contain >`

That's where I get stuck. There's no way to reference the adjacent cell.

How can something like this be done (without using VBA/Macros)?

Comment: Double border cannot be used in conditional formatting because it affects row height. Does it have to be a double border?

Comment: Actually, Yes. But I can do with a single border line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply it like this:

[image]

Make sure that the current cell selected is where you want the formatting to apply. Once you have done that, you can apply the same rule to the whole column through 'Manage Rules' by changing the range of 'Applies to' to the whole column:

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned that the data isn't just that much. There are some 300+ rows. Seems your solution works only for a single row.

Comment: @Norman you need to apply it to the whole column as I mentioned in my answer. See that the 'Applies to' has been changed later to `=$B:$B`